# How do you add a ruby file to an existing project in Eclipse 3.6 using the Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK)?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, dltk

I've installed the Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK) in Eclipse 3.6.  But I can't figure out how to create a Ruby file in an existing Java project.

Doing the obvious thing (New -> Empty Ruby Script) just gives the error message "Source folder is not a correct project".  Do I have to modify the project in some way to tell DLTK that it's OK to add Ruby files to it?

(Adding the file outside of Eclipse does work.)

Comment: Is there a reason that you  want to include a ruby file in a java project? The normal way is to create a ruby project, and to create there the new ruby file. I have done that with Indigo, and I can then copy the ruby file to the Java project as a workaround. I'm even able to run then the ruby file, or edit it in a Ruby editor.

Comment: Two reasons.  First, I'd turn this around - is there a reason you'd want to create a whole ruby project, when all you want are a couple ruby scripts that $DO_SOMETHING_TO_THE_JAVA_PROJECT?  In my case, I want to do some preprocessing with jruby, and an entire ruby project for that seems silly.  Second - jruby.  These days, a "java" project is really more of a "jvm" project - it's not just java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps (has worked for me):

1. Create a java project, or visit an existing one.
2. Select in the directory you want the ruby file to live in the menu entry `New file` and enter in the dialog the filename `my_file.rb`. The essential part is the extension, because this will ensure that the ruby mechanisms are in place.
3. Enter in the new ruby file `def` and press `CTRL-SPACE`, you should see as a result the list with `def - method definition` (the template), `def` and `defined?`. This  is all part of the ruby text editor.

So it is possible to mix java and ruby files in the same project, that has as nature java. The only thing I has noticed is that the run menu entry only allows you to start the dialog `Run As > Run Configurations...` and enter there the necessary parameters to start your ruby script.