# Multiple nature for a single project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

is it possible to add multiple nature to a single project in eclipse ?

eg: i want to add Python and Ruby nature to a Java project.

the purpose.
I have solutions to projecteuler.net problems in Java,Ruby,Scala,Clojure and Python.
But the solutions are in different projects.
I need them in a single project.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404716/how-do-you-add-a-ruby-file-to-an-existing-project-in-eclipse-3-6-using-the-dynami/7423864#7423864, perhaps that is sufficient for what you want to do. There I have included 1 Ruby file in a Java project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GUI does not have any option for creating such a multilanguage projects.

However, technically, project natures can be added independently from each other. So if you manage to programmatically create the required environment, it would work. If you want to do it manually, find the .project file in the project root, and add all natures and builders to one (you can look the required elements from other projects - do a copy-paste).

This would add the project natures and builders, but not any additional configuration required - e.g. in Java projects .classpath files are used to describe the source folders, in other languages different configurations are needed.

Alltogether, if you need to do this multiple times, create a plug-in that manages this configuration for you; if you need it for a single project, think about it whether it is worth the huge effort required.