# How can I run cucumber scenarios crossbrowser?

Tags: java, selenium, cross-browser, webdriver, cucumber

so I have set up my step definitions and cucumber scenarios and they r running fine using firefox (since my step def are using firefox webdriver) but now I need to run my scenarios crossbrowser. I have been looking at selenium grid as an option but would greatly appreciate if someone can guide me on how to run my cucumber scenarios crossbrowser. 
thanks

Comment: start using QMetry Automation Framework, [gherkin factory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.9/gherkin_client.html#benefits-of-using-qaf-gherkin-scenario-factory) and configure driver in xml configuration file

Answer (score 1):

When running WebDriver using any browser that is not Firefox you will need to use a third-party WebDriver.

Use the links Aravin has provided to download the WebDrivers.

You will also need to set a system property to where the third party driver files are located.

Here's an example of setting up a new ChromeDriver instance in Java:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

IE:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",  "path/to/iedriver.exe");
WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

This should set you up a local instance for the above browsers.

If you are thinking of using grid, you can find plenty of info in the [docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the corresponding driver for the browser to execute your scenario.

**For Chrome**: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

**For IE**: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

**For Safari**: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

You can configure this in `env.rb` file of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... do you have any example of this implementation? I have developed my framework using Java, Selenium & Cucumber so how would I go about incorporating a ruby file? any example would be very helpful. thanks

Comment: I have found some info in ruby integration with my Java project (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404716/how-do-you-add-a-ruby-file-to-an-existing-project-in-eclipse-3-6-using-the-dynam) so I will give that a try for now :) ... thanks